# Interpolating scattered 3D electric field data

Tags: matlab

I have measured electric field data in three dimensions of the following form:

```
 pos = [x1 y1 z1
        x2 y2 z2
         .  .  . 
        x1000 y1000 z1000]
 ef = [e_x1 e_y1 e_z1
       e_x2 e_y2 e_z2
         .    .    . 
       e_x1000 e_y1000 e_z1000]
```

The positions are located within a half sphere. I want to be able to interpolate the electric field at some point of the sphere, so that I receive all the three values of the electric field components, not just the norm of the whole field. interp3 won't work as the points are not in a grid. scatteredInterpolant needs the norm as the input, and the generated function only returns the norm. Any suggestions on what function to use or how to solve this problem?

Comment: `griddata` is probably what you want

Comment: The function takes the sample values as a vector, and not an array, according to the documentation. So it would use the norm as well I think?

Comment: What do you mean "the norm" ? Also, what do you mean "a vector, not an array"? what is the difference?

Comment: You just need to do `griddata(pos(:,1),pos(:,2),pos(:,3),ef(:,1),yourpointsx,yourpointsy)`

Comment: Sorry, I meant a matrix. 

By the norm I mean the second norm of the vector. So `sqrt(e_x^2 + e_y^2 + e_z^2)`. Does your second comment compute the x component of the efield at certain spot?

Comment: You clearly do not need the norm in none of the functions. My second comment missed a `,yourpointsz)` in the end. Yes, it computes exactly that. You can do the same for the other components. Caution: any non-uniform interpolation is computationally very expensive.

Comment: Why does the value differ when you use 

`griddata(pos(:,1),pos(:,2),pos(:,3),e_norm,x,y,z)` versus calculating the 3 components separately, and computing the norm from those values? Am I missing something fundamental here, or should it not be the same? Also, thank you very much for the help so far. :)

Comment: It should not be the same necessarily, you will need to chose which one is more relevant for you.

Answer (score 0):

`scatteredInterpolant` only interpolates one column of samples at a time, but one way to interpolate a vector field is to interpolate each component of the vector independently.

This is straightforward with `scatteredInterpolant`.

```
componentInterpolants = cellfun(@(v) {scatteredInterpolant(pos,v)}, num2cell(ef,1));
```

This leaves you with a cell array of three `scatteredInterpolant` objects, one for each cartesian component of the field. By evaluating each of them individually for the specified coordinates and concatenating the result you get an electric field vector for each given coordinates. You could define a convenience function to give you the interpolated vector field in full for a given set off coordinates:

```
efInterpolant = @(coords) cell2mat(cellfun(@(interpolant) {interpolant(coords)}, componentInterpolants));
```

Verify that this interpolates the original vector field exactly (barring floating point error):

```
assert(all(all(abs(ef - efInterpolant(pos)) < eps * 2)));
```

If interpolating each cartesian component independently doesn't maintain some relationship between the vector components you expect within this field then you might need a different numerical method – perhaps some coordinate transformation before taking the same interpolation approach – but that's probably more a question for the Mathematics Stack Exchange site.